# Change the "queries per second per user" allowed for Google Analytics API

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, quota

I'm getting an [error 403 userRateLimitExceeded](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors)  when trying to use my Google Analytics API to fetch data for more than one site at a time.

The documentation tells me to set QPS (queries per second) to 10 in the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard). I can't find this setting anywhere.

How can I set the QPS for my Google Analytics API to 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) go to the API manager over view.  click the quota tab and then the little pencil thing.

[image]

default is one request a second.  you can set it up to 10

Tip:  if you are still having issues look into sending [quotauser](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/parameters) you can trick it a little by sending a random number with each request.

Comment: Thanks! By "send it a random number with each request", where are you providing this ID?

Comment: tac it on to the end of your request to the api https ://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:12345
  &start-date=2008-10-01
  &end-date=2008-10-31  &metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces&oauth_token=AccessToken&quotaUser=Xyz